# Rerouting requests from site.org/old to site.org/new in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have a site deployed at `www.site.org`. I have routes at `www.site.org/old/article` and I want to automatically redirect people to `www.site.org/new/article`. Ideally this would work as a wildcard to capture anything and not just article.

I'm not great at Nginx so any advice would be useful on best practices. I have seen a few people do it with location blocks with a mixture of `return 301` woven in as well as straight up rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an HTTP 301 permanent redirect rather than serving the old URL like it is a new one, use

```
rewrite ^/old(/.*) /new$1 permanent;
```

If I am wrong and you want to serve both `/old/article` and `/new/article` the same way without a redirection, use the same rewrite rule without the `permanent` flag (should be placed at the `server` context, not the `location` one!):

```
rewrite ^/old(/.*) /new$1;
```